# Wind-blown skirt {Marilyn Monroe style} - dealing with pleated/ribbed material?

Tags: cloth-simulation, force-fields

I'm familiar with force fields/wind and creating rippling/wind blown "basic" cloth, and 0 knowledge in anything more than the basics. I'd like to take it a step further and recreate the Monroe skirt, in its wind-blown style.

I don't know how to approach the pleats. In real material, pleats are soft and they do stretch with the skirt, somewhat, but they also keep some of their shape. (see ref images)

If I use wind on cloth within blender, it flattens any type of detail in the cloth, so i'm looking for ideas :')

Is there a way to prep a pleated/ribbed skirt model where the pleats have those type of constraints, with *some* stretch, and not completely disappearing or completely stiff? Would it have to somehow involve vertex groups? I have no clue where to start :') thank you.

[image: pleated skirt]

[image: wind-blown]